# bazel run immediately Segmentation faults

Tags: c++, bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to use a locally built package ([this one](https://github.com/gabyx/ApproxMVBB)) within an existing bazel project. It bazel builds without any errors, but when I try to bazel run it, it immediately segfaults. I tried building it in debug mode, but when I run it in debug mode it still immediately segfaults without any useful error message.

I built the external package following the instructions in the README and the examples run fine (outside of bazel), so I know that the external libraries are not the issue.

I made a repository to access this package in my `WORKSPACE` file

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "ApproxMVBB",
    path = "/absolute/path/to/ApproxMVBB",
    build_file = "approxmvbb.BUILD", )
```

The `approxmvbb.BUILD` file looks like this

```
cc_library(
    name = "ApproxMVBB-lib",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.a"])+glob(["**/*.so"]),
    hdrs = glob(["**/*.hpp"]),
    includes = ["include", "build/include", "external/Diameter/include", "external/GeometryPredicates/include"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

And the cc_binary I am trying to run looks like this

```
cc_binary(
    name = "TestMVBB",
    srcs = [
        "src/test_approxmvbb.cpp",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@ApproxMVBB//:ApproxMVBB-lib",
    ],
    linkopts = ["-shared"],
)
```

The source code for the binary `src/test_approvmvbb.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ApproxMVBB/ComputeApproxMVBB.hpp"

int  main(int argc, char** argv)
{
      ApproxMVBB::Matrix3Dyn points(3,10000);
      points.setRandom();
      ApproxMVBB::OOBB oobb = ApproxMVBB::approximateMVBB(points,0.001,500,5,0,5);
      oobb.expandToMinExtentRelative(0.1);
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistakes. First, I was changing a lot of things and forgot to rebuild the external package, so the libraries didn't exist... oops.

But more importantly, when the external package is built, it outputs library files that have file extensions other than `.o` and `.so` so I had to change the following line in the `cc_library` target

```
srcs = glob(["**/*.a"])+glob(["**/*.so"])+glob(["**/*.so.2.1.1"]),
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!!